# Microsoft Access - Record Form Load

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am curious whether it is possible that when i load a record in one of my forms and i choose to add a quote for that record selected, so i choose add quote (button) which takes me to my quote page. i would then like the form to auto load the record i had previously selected in the other form.

Client Form:

[image]

Quote Form:
[image]
Here is the data flow:
Record Selected ("Add Job") > Click "Add Items" button > "Items List" loads > the record i previously selected in "Add Job" is then auto loaded.

the feild that will need loading are "Project ID" & "Client name"

Comment: In what language are you trying to do this?  Please edit in your code where you are trying to do this.

Comment: Sorry this would be in microsoft Access - so using VBA code and system functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `OpenArgs` argument of the `DoCmd.OpenForm` method

[image]

---

- When you click `Add Quotes` button to open Quotes form, send the details/linked ID via openArgs parameter.
- In Quotes form load event, you can get the details passed using `Me.OpenArgs`

See below sample code

---

> On Add Quotes button click

```
Private Sub AddQuotes_Click()

    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmQuotes", OpenArgs:=me.ClientID

End Sub
```

> Quotes form

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim varArgs

    varArgs = Me.OpenArgs

    'Fill the controls with recordset data
    If Not IsNull(varArgs) Then
        With CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblClients WHERE ClientID = " & varArgs, dbOpenForwardOnly )
                Me.ClientID = !ClientID
                Me.ClientName = !ClientName
                Me.ClientAddress = !ClientAddress
                Me.ClientPhone = !ClientPhone
                Me.ClientEmail = !ClientEmail
            .Close
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: OpenArgs:=me.ClientID, as i do not have clientID as a field i have used project_ID but it will not recognise this. look at updated forms to see fields

Comment: The above sample code shows how it has to be done. You need to pass data from your old form to new form in `OpenArgs:=me.Project_ID` parameter. Where are you stuck?

Comment: So i would like to pass through the Project ID ("Combo97") And Client Name ("Combo604") they will be taken to the "Items List" Form. it will not register the Project_ID feild in the OnClick() event

Comment: would sending you a copy of the system help?