# How to pass values between forms in MS-Access?

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I am using Access 2013. 
I have a main form that consists of three subforms. I want to be able to pass data between two forms.

One of the subforms is in datasheet view and I am trying to have it update when the user updates data to the table via a dialog form. This dialog form is initiated using a button that is just above the Compliant subform (datasheet icon).

I am not sure if I must use VBA code to initiate the update. 
Here are a few images of what I am working on.
[image: The subform as a datasheet view]

[image: The dialog form initiated by the "New" button command]

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

I am currently searching through StackOverFlow for any leads,

Comment: You don't really need to 'pass' values, you just need to refresh data. Could use button on ribbon or try `Me.Requery` in VBA behind the main form. Edit question to post code that opens the dialog form.

Comment: I understand that a button can be used and the Me.Requery 
The dialog form is opened using button that has a macro associated with it.

Comment: See if this helps  https://stackoverflow.com/a/51428937/2227085

Comment: Hi, thank you. I had tried using the code but gosh I clearly can't get that silly datasheet to update on the subsection. It is saving to the master table which is good but without the FK which is important. 
I am searching for Access training because this is advanced for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access subforms' controls in main forms or other forms with this structure:

```
Forms!parentName!subformName.Form.ControlName
```

And you can access forms' controls in main forms or other forms with this structure:

```
Forms!parentName!ControlName
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use macros, only VBA. Example code for opening a form then requerying the main form:

```
Private Sub btnSPG_Click()
DoCmd.OpenForm "BituminousMixToolsSPG", , , , , acDialog
Me.Refresh
End Sub
```

`acDialog` suspends code execution of calling procedure until the called form closes. When the code execution resumes the Refresh command executes (or use Requery command). Don't know if macro can do Refresh or Requery, I'll let you figure that one out.

Might have to directly target the subform for Requery:
`Me.subformcontainername.Requery`

Comment: Macros can do Refresh and Requery. 
I am a bit confused. The Me.Refresh is to update which part of the form?
I tried it on the main form and it refreshed before I was able to enter the rest of the form data which is understood but of course it should remain on the form till the entire form is filled through.

This refresh for the button which you provided the sample code, is it for the close button after entering data in the dialog form?

Comment: It's intended to refresh/requery everything - the main form and subform. I did show code if you want to target the subform alone.